# redux not calling mapStateToProps on store update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Do not use `push` while updating your state. Use `concat`**

I'm facing this really strange issue, consider this reducer:

```
export default function(state = null, action) {

  console.log("Current State: ",state);
  // on performing actions, it gives me:
  // Current State: null
  // Current State: Array [{}]
  // Current State: Array [{}] -- all good

  if(state === null) {
      state = [
          {id: 1, title: "Java"}
      ];
  }

  // UPDATED PART. FORGOT TO MENTION IT BEFORE
  if(Action.type == "UPDATE_LIST") {
     state.push( Action.payload ); // don't do that, this'll mutate your array and states are immutable
  }
  /////////////

  return state; // this is the main problem
}
```

The above code does not invoke `mapStateToProps` inside my component. However, modifying the above reducer like down below does invoke `mapStateToProps`:

```
return []; // instead of return state;
```

OR

```
return [ {id: 1, title: "Python"} ]; // instead of return state;
```

I'm returning instanceof Array in both cases [ state & [] ], but only the latter one is invoking `mapStateToProps` in my component.

This is strange, and I've no idea what am I suppose to do to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The point of redux is to ensure that your state is not directly mutable. Since Arrays and objects are passed by reference in Javascript, your code is attempting to mutate the state object directly..which is incorrect.

Always mutate the state by returning the new state. Like this:

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
  let newState = [...state];
  if(state === null) {
      newstate = [
          {id: 1, title: "Java"}
      ];
  }

  return newState;
}
```

Comment: while it's seem about right, it's hard to imagine STATE to be immutable.. you know like it's state.. it changes

Comment: My  mistake..I wasnt clear enough. What I mean is that the redux lifeycle works by ensuring that the only way to change your state, is by dispatching an action which would get processed by a reducer which would then return the updated state. So nowhere in your code should `state.data = newData` exist. it should always be updated via an action.

Comment: The point of doing all this work is to ensure that your state is never inconsistent (since only actions can mutate it), that you can track how your state got to a certain point (by tracking the actions that were dispatched) and other such perks.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles) for further understanding of the basic principles

Comment: okay, this may sound incredibly stupid on my part, but what I didn't mention is that I wasn't assigning the new array to the state but was pushing to it which I thought wouldn't matter. though after learning about state immutability I've realized it actually mattered the most. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

do like this way :

```
 if(state === null) {
      state = [
          {id: 1, title: "Java"}
      ]; 
      return state;
  }

  return state;
```

Comment: what is difference between my way and immediately returning the updated state (your way)??

Comment: I did try that out. It didn't work. It still wouldn't call the `mapStateToProps` function on my component, but if I were to return, let's say, an empty array [ ] instead of that accumulated state it works like a charm

Comment: okay, this may sound incredibly stupid on my part, but what I didn't mention is that I wasn't assigning the new array to the state but was pushing to it which I thought wouldn't matter. though after learning about state immutability I've realized it actually mattered the most. thank you for your time.